# I need to narrow down what data pulls through on the Access Report?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

I want to show water cost under `OFFICE` if between 5-7 days after RR. If after 7 days, show under `RECEIVED AFTER WELL CLOSED`, everything under 5 days shows up under `FIELD`.

This is the current code being used that has not been updated to reflect the above criteria:

```
Entry: IIf(Date()>=[RR]+5,"OFFICE","FIELD")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed another if condition into the formula:

```
IIf(Date()>=[RR]+7,"RECEIVED AFTER WELL CLOSED",IIf(Data()>=[RR]+5,"OFFICE","FIELD"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`switch`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) function for this task:

```
switch
(
    Date()-RR >  7, "RECEIVED AFTER WELL CLOSED",
    Date()-RR >= 5, "OFFICE",
    True, "FIELD"
)
```